# Probable error in array declaration for sorting array of length 1M

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I am required to use Selection Sort to sort out arrays of the lengths of 100K, 150K, 200K and 1M and display the time required to sort out each array, and the number of element to element comparisons.

I did this by making an array having the elements as the lengths of the arrays. Then I ran a for loop with said array and passed the element being used as the size of the unsorted array to be created and created a randomly generated array.

I then use a function call to sort.

The program ran with no problem for my first 3 array lengths ( 100K, 150K and 200K ), however it did not run at all for 1M array length sorting.

I was not able to figure out at which point of the program was it stopping execution. I first thought that the problem lies with my integer declarations as some of them were storing quantities as big as a million. For this I put printf statements periodically to  understand where the flow of the program was getting interrupted and it was surprisingly the array declaration ( this is what it seems like to me, not sure though ).

I have attached the code and output that I got.

Code:

```
// C program for implementation of selection sort 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long int counterS = 0; //counter for number of element to element comparisons


void swap(int *xp, int *yp) //swap function
{ 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 

void selectionSort(int arr[], long long int n) 
{ 
    long long int i, j, min_idx;    //used long long int cuz they reach upto 10^6 order

    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray 
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
    { 
        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array 
        min_idx = i; 
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx]) 
                min_idx = j; 
            ++counterS;             //increments each time a comparison occurs
        }
        // Swap the found minimum element with the first element 
        swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]); 
    } 
} 


// Driver program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    clock_t tic1, toc1;
    int sz[4]={100000,150000, 200000, 1000000}; //array having array lengths  
    int k;

    for(k=0;k<4;k++){
    printf("1st check: It's the long long int declaration\n");  //1st check to get to know where it went wrong
    long long int size = sz[k];
    printf("2nd check: It's the array declaration\n");          //2nd check to know where it went wrong
    int arr[size];
    printf("3rd check: It's not the array declaration\n");      //3rd check to know where it went wrong

    long long int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        arr[i]=rand()%100;

    long long int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    printf("4th check: It's the random array generation\n");    //4th check to know where it went wrong

    tic1 = clock();
    selectionSort(arr, n); 
    toc1 = clock();
    double time_taken = (double)(toc1-tic1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("5th check: It's the function call\n");              //5th check to know where it went wrong

    printf("Selection Sort - time = %lf seconds, element by element comparisons = %lld\n",
    time_taken, counterS );
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
1st check: It's the long long int declaration
2nd check: It's the array declaration
3rd check: It's not the array declaration
4th check: It's the random array generation
5th check: It's the function call
Selection Sort - time = 11.458000 seconds, element by element comparisons = 4999950000
1st check: It's the long long int declaration
2nd check: It's the array declaration
3rd check: It's not the array declaration
4th check: It's the random array generation
5th check: It's the function call
Selection Sort - time = 59.196000 seconds, element by element comparisons = 16249875000
1st check: It's the long long int declaration
2nd check: It's the array declaration
3rd check: It's not the array declaration
4th check: It's the random array generation
5th check: It's the function call
Selection Sort - time = 120.349000 seconds, element by element comparisons = 36249775000
1st check: It's the long long int declaration
2nd check: It's the array declaration
```

Comment: It may be too big for your stack. Consider allocating on heap (using `malloc()`) instead.

Comment: I thought so too, however, the solution is required to be done with arrays as according to the course portions we haven't dealt with heaps as of yet. My peers have been able to solve said problem statement with arrays.

Comment: What is your environment? Executing command `ulimit -s unlimited` (remove limitation on the stack size) on your shell might be helpful.

Comment: The data type `int` in C is capable of holding numbers up-to 2^32 (4e9), you could try making the `long long int` to `int` and see if you are able to declare the array.

Comment: @ANIRUDHBUVANESH Trying is OK, but it won't be helpful. More hopeful try will be using `char` instead of `int` as the element of the array to save memory. The random number is at most 100, so signed `char` that can store upto 127 will be enough.

Comment: `int arr[size];` - use `malloc`

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using? You can usually increase the allocated stack size for a process at link time. You may also have to make changes to OS configuration as well.

Answer (score 1):

Define your large array outside any function.

```
int large[1000000];
int main(void) {
    int sz[4] = {100000, 150000, 200000, 1000000};
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        // use the first sz[k] elements of large
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since everything else is working i would say you dont have enough bits to allocate a continious array of 1M size on the go, so as others commented i would suggest `malloc()` .
Others in your class may have this working because on their machine there is enough stack space to allocate 1M on the go. See if `malloc()` solves it and then you will know for sure.